# C# Oracle execute stored procedure with output parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, parameters, procedure

Situation:

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that has an output parameter, which I need to catch.

I use C# 3.5 and the OracleClient with an OleDbConnection.

Research:

I've been looking around for other ways, but as far as I can tell I'm doing it correct. [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070) and various other forums.

Problem:

When I do the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() it just gets stuck. No error or anything, it just stops there and holds the Thread.

When I try via OleDbDataReader or the Scalar it's nothing better.

If I change the CommandText (remove package name) it gives error that it can't find the stored procedure, so I know that is correct at least.

Code:
Oracle:

```
PROCEDURE deleteThemakaart
(an_seqthemakaart IN NUMBER, an_retval OUT NUMBER)
....
```

C#:

```
double InputValue = 777;
try
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(...);
    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()
    {
        CommandText = "thema.pckg_themakaarten.deleteThemakaart",
        Connection = con,
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    };

    OleDbParameter input = cmd.Parameters.Add("an_seqthemakaart", OleDbType.Double);
    OleDbParameter output = cmd.Parameters.Add("an_retval", OleDbType.Double);

    input.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    output.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    input.Value = InputValue;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return (double)output.Value;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Any help is very welcome :)

Edit: some code is below in comment, but hasn't gotten me any further so far :(

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried calling the procedure directly, i.e. with a PL/SQL script? So just to exclude the possibility that the procedure itself doesn't return.

Comment: How about setting the direction in `Add` itself ?

Comment: If I call the stored procedure in SqlNavigator it works perfectly. And I can't set the Direction directly in Add can I? I could add .Direction = ... but then it won't return the OleDbParameter.

Comment: Have you tried with a different type for the parameters instead of OleDbType.Double? The identifier should rather be an Integer (or BigInt) I guess.

Comment: I used Double because when I used an XSD scheme to get data it converted it to Doubles. But even when I try with Decimal/Integer/BigInt it didn't work as well.

Comment: The weird thing is, when I browse my Server Explorer I can see the Stored Procedure, but when I try to add it to my XSD schematic it says the procedure doesn't exist. But I can add some other ones in different packages.When I then check the code and update my CommandText in the same syntax, it gives error that it can't find it. Such as: CommandText = string.Format("\"THEMA\".\"PCKG_THEMAKAARTEN\".\"{0}\"", ProcedureName),

Comment: @FrieK: have you considered using ODAC (Oracle Data Access Component)? I've had loads of problems in the past using MS provider, especially when you deal with stored procedures (packages) etc. The ODAC is stable, works very well with SPs and it's faster -> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the trouble maker... one of the tables that the procedure used was locked.